# How can i write the unit test for tempfile?

Tags: python-unittest

```
import tempfile

def tmpdir(destdir=None):

    return tempfile.mkdtemp(suffix='.' + str(os.getpid()), dir=destdir)
```

Comment: What aspect of `tmpdir()` are you trying to test?

Comment: tmpdir: creates and returns an absolute path to a temporary directory.

Comment: You may test, that the path is absolute, the path leads to a directory and you have a R/W access to the directory (including directory deletion). However, your function just delegates actual work to the `mkdtemp` - are you sure you don't have more suitable function for testing?